# C language: copy data from one typedef struct to another and return a value

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I am new in C & I am currently working with structures. I am stuck & I would be very grateful if somebody came to my rescue.
So I have a function to write input data from the main module to the sub-module.
It should return 0 if it writes successfully, & 1 if it doesn't succeed.
I have been reading widely but I am still unsure whether to use memcpy or not. 
Then, on the return value I have read that memcpy returns 0 if the operation was successful and 1 if it was not. Here is that part of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    UINT32 carnum_n;
    UINT32 carnum_k;
    UINT32 results[30];
    UINT32 feedback[30];  
    UINT32 errors[30];
} MAIN;

typedef struct {
   UINT32 carnum_n;
   UINT32 carnum_k;
   UINT32 feedback[30];
} SETTING;

/* function to copy the data from the main to the sub-module */    
UINT32 Write( MAIN *data, SETTING *info)
{
   sc_memcpy ( &info->carnum_k, &data->carnum_k, sizeof (SETTING));
   sc_memcpy ( &info->feedback, &data->feedback, sizeof (SETTING));  //copies the array
}
```

1. Please tell me, is this correct? If not, what is the correct way to write it? Or what other alternatives do I have?
2. As I have an array as well, how should I go about it?  What changes when I have to save say upto fb[10] from the main module to the sub-module?
3. How do I incoorporate the return condition, given that I should seemingly write ONE line of code to copy each type of data from the main module's table to the sub-module's input table?

I really want to get this right. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Why are you making two separate typedefs for the same thing?

Comment: both the `memcpy()` operations are wrong.

Comment: @n.'pronouns' m. One is the source (from the input via the main module), the other is the destination file (to be used in the current sub-module). So the contents are the same.

Comment: From [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) you can see that using `memcpy(dst, dst_size, src, byte_count)` will return 0 on success or non-zero on failure. You should be accessing your struct addresses with `sc_memcpy (info, data, sizeof (MAIN));`.

Comment: @Inian,I suspected. thanks. How should I write them?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. is asking why the structs are identical, but there are two different ones. You can use the same struct typedef for either since they _are the same_

Comment: The source and the destination are different objects, but why are you giving them different **types**?

Comment: @Nathan Wride, I am looking up the reference you've attached, thanks. About the structs, maybe i should include more data in the main for the difference to come out clearly. I'll do it. They aren't meant to be identical anyway so that whatever sub-module needs data from the main it can just access what it needs and leave the rest.

Comment: You don't need memcpy at all as they are scalar types.  You can do `data->carnum_k = info->carnum_k;` for example.  You can even copy whole `struct`s this way and the compiler will call an internal `memcpy()` itself, on your behalf.

Comment: @ n. 'pronouns' m, different types because they are stored in different data tables. MAIN points to the data in the main module, which can be accessed by any sub-module, while SETTING is the input data used in the current sub module.

Comment: @ trojanfoe Thanks. But the feedback array feedback[30] isn't scalar, yes? So can it stay the way it is or that's wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't use `memcpy`, but rather a mysterious function `sc_memcpy` defined nowhere here nor in the alleged reference given by Nathan Wride, so the discussion is rather pointless.

Comment: @Armali no idea what this `sc_memcpy` is. Just provided reference to `memcpy` and `memcpy_s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1, your code is not correct.

When copy `carnum_k`, the `sizeof(SETTING)` is wrong. `sizeof (SETTING)` means the size of all data in `SETTING` structure .  But you just need copy `carnum_k`, so you need provide the size of `carnum_k`, which is `sizeof (UINT32)`, `UINT32` is the type of `carnum_k`.

```
memcpy ( &info->carnum_k, &data->carnum_k, sizeof (UINT32));
```

You can also just write an assignment `info->carnum_k = data->carnum_k`.

The copy of feedback has two problem.

1. `sizeof (SETTING)` is wrong just like when you copy `carnum_k`. You can use `sizeof(UINT32 [30])`, `UINT32 [30]` is the type of `feedback`.
2. `info->feedback` is an array address, so no need `&info->feedback`, just `info->feedback`.

```
memcpy(info->feedback, data->feedback, sizeof(UINT32 [30]));
```

Question 2. I think you mean you may want just copy part of `feedback`.

When you copy memory you need figure out src memory address, dest memory address, and the size of memory you want to copy.

so if you want copy from `feedback[2]` to `feedback[10]`.

- source address is `&(data->feedback[2])`
- dest address is `&(info->feedback[2])`.
- From 2 to 10, there is 9 value you want to copy, so the total size is `9 * sizeof(UINT32)`

```
memcpy(&(info->feedback[2]), &(data->feedback[2]), 9*sizeof(UINT32));
```

Question 3.

I don't known the answer.

Comment: Xianggang ZENG, thank you so much for taking your time to respond, & for offering explanations as well. I really appreciate it. I just started learning & using C recently so it is quite motivating to receive such good feedback. Thank you once again :)